# 'put_item' to dynamodb is failing due to lxml attribute error

Tags: python, xml, amazon-dynamodb, lxml

I am trying to write data to a table in DynamoDB. The Item is multiple AWS AMI IDs and the attributes are OS, vulnerability risk levels, and packages. I have an XML file I am reading from in S3. There are multiple `<IMAGE_ID>` tags, so I am using the `findall()` method to parse all the image IDs and the children elements (OS, vulnerability risk level etc.). When I try to write this data to the table I get the following error:

`'list' object has no attribute 'text'`

`Code:`

```
import boto3
import os
import lxml
from lxml import etree

def WriteItemToTable():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
    key = 'XXXXX.xml'
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('ExistingAMI')

    os.chdir('/tmp')
    s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(key, 'XXXX.xml')
    f = open("XXXX.xml","r")
    tree = etree.parse(f)

    for i in tree.find('HOST_LIST'):
        image_id = i.findall('EC2_INFO/IMAGE_ID').text
        os_id = i.findall('OPERATING_SYSTEM').text
        sev_score = i.findall('VULN_INFO_LIST/VULN_INFO/CVSS_FINAL').text
        patch_info = i.findall('VULN_INFO_LIST/VULN_INFO/RESULT').text

        table.put_item(Item={'AMI_ID': image_id, 'OS':os_id, 'Severity': sev_score, 'Patches': patch_info,})

WriteItemToTable()
```

So, obviously the `findall()` method isn’t responding to `.text.` But, I am not sure what other way to parse these values.

Comment: `findall()` returns a list of elements. The list itself has no `text` property, but each member of the list has.

Comment: @mzjn So, how would I parse those elements? With another for loop?

Comment: Yes, if you have a list of IMAGE_ID elements, you'd have to iterate over those elements and obtain the text from each of them, or something like that. It would be easier to help if you provided a [mcve]. We cannot execute the code in the question as it looks right now. The fact that you use boto and dynamodb seems irrelevant when diagnosing the error that you get.